# 504 Error AWS Server gateway timeout after apache(httpd) configuration with mod_wsgi for django app in redhat

Tags: header, timeout, redhat, mod-wsgi, daemon

I got an error called Gateway Timeout when trying to load my server elastic ip. I changed documents root to **/var/www/public_html** My OS is Redhat AWS EC2 Instance

**My projects root is**

1. /var/www/public_html
2. /var/www/public_html/main
3. /var/www/public_html/main/wsgi.py

**When i Run this command to check Configuration File Error**

```
sudo httpd -t
```

**Result is**

```
[Tue Oct 05 01:32:39.954924 2021] [so:warn] [pid 417878:tid 139824059787584] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
```

Syntax OK

**I am Using python3-mod_wsgi**

[image]

**Error is**

> [wsgi:error] [pid 415061:tid 140537755555584] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'main': /var/www/public_html/main/wsgi.py

**My virtual host configuration file `/etc/httpd/sites-available/vhosts.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that

    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating

    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName

    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to

    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this

    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.

    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    #ServerName www.example.com


    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,

    # error, crit, alert, emerg.

    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular

    # modules, e.g.

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn


     ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/3.109.245.1-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/3.109.245.1-access.log combined


    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are

    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to

    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the

    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only

    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


    Alias /static /var/www/public_html/static

    <Directory /var/www/public_html/static>

        Require all granted

    </Directory>


    <Directory /var/www/public_html/main>

        <Files wsgi.py>

            Require all granted

        </Files>

    </Directory>


    WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIDaemonProcess main  python-path=/var/www/public_html/main/  python-home=/var/www/public_html/venv

    WSGIProcessGroup main

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/public_html/main/wsgi.py
```

**My httpd(apache) configuration file httpd.conf**

```html
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

   
    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>  
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>   
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
  
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
   
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
   
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
   
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>   
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

**My wsgi.py**

```html
"""
WSGI config for main project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#sys.path.append('/var/www/public_html/main/')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```